# Best practice about C++ modularity

Tags: c++, modularity

Is a good practice to allways separate the declaration and the definition even if the definition has a only line, like the constructor or `int value() const;` in the code bellow?

My goal is to learn C++ and, at the same time, incorporate the best practices. So if there is something to improve in this code please tell me.

```
//counter.h
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H
#include <QObject>


class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Counter();
    int value() const;

public slots:
    void setValue(int value);

signals:
    void valueChange(int newValue);
private:
    int m_value;
};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

-

```
//counter.cpp
#include "counter.h"

Counter::Counter()
{
    m_value = 0;
}

int Counter::value() const
{
    return m_value;
}

void Counter::setValue(int value)
{
    if(value != m_value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChange(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very much an opinion based question, and not entirely appropriate here.  There are reasons for doing it either way.  Doing it like this can prevent the compiler from inlining your constructor which ultimately hurts performance.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm On the other side, there exist those damned header only libraries like most of the boost's... :-)

Comment: C++ modules feature will likely make them equal

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Sorry, i don't know where to ask. If I use the keyword inline it'll be solved, is it true?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Have you ever heard about a link time code generation? It is more than 10 years old. Thanks to it, your statement about not inlining a constructor is not true.

Comment: @MarianSpanik I said _can_, not _will_, because of LTCG.  It's something you have to turn on and is not universally supported.

Comment: @Pablo `inline` **is** different from non-`inline`. By using `inline` you basically require the body of the function to be present in the same compilation unit (eg defined in a header file if used by multiple `.cpp` files). This is the only non-opinion-based aspect of your question that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions implemented inside class definition is inline. So if you put these methods inside class definition you'll make them all inline. This is not equivalent code.

Best practice in C++ is moving to .cpp file as many definitions as possible and keeping your .h file as easy as possible. Reduce the number if `#include` directives in your header files. Use forward declarations of your classes and structs instead of full definitions where possible.

Alas, these guidelines will not work with templates, that's why C++ compilation is so slow.

Comment: The "best practice" part is opinion based as many "best practices" are. You then conclude with your "best practices" doesn't work with all language features (which means that one could question if they're always best).

Comment: Just a note: both the `inline` keyword, and being implicitly inline due to definition within a class definition, are *hints* to the compiler and not binding: increasingly, compiler's make their own decisions about when to inline functions for which the definition is known in the translation unit, though they may need command line arguments to consider inlining code from another translation unit (which is desirable, as it makes it hard to recompile just the translation unit with the implementation and relink).

Comment: @TonyD Although note that `inline`, implicit or not, is binding vis à vis the ODR rule.

Comment: @TonyD The `inline` keyword has semantics, but maybe not what you might believe. The `inline` keyword means that the function body must appear identically in every translation unit where it's used and the address of the function must be the same in each translation unit (basically this simplifies for the compiler to choose to inline or not).

Comment: @skyking: There will be plethora of opportunities to make the project compile for 40 minutes on a small Xeon cluster, so why wasting time on this simple Qt widget?